# Meaning of Dummy Variable

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, predictive-models

I am working on a case study from Kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/liberty-mutual-fire-peril

Here, in the variables, there is a variable: "Dummy" about which the description says:

(dummy: Nuisance variable used to control the model, but not working as a predictor.)

What does it mean?

PS: It is a regression problem. It has total of 302 variables out of which 300 variables have to be used in prediction.

Comment: Probably you should learn the basics of reression on a simpler example before trying kaggle competitions.

Comment: Would definitely echo with @kjetilbhalvorsen's suggestion.

It would take you a long way, not only in Kaggle competitions, but also in most data problem analyses.

Answer (score 1):

a "dummy" is a variable that can take only two values (usually 0 or 1). A typical example is female or male dummy, where female=1 indicates that the observation was for a female and the estimation coefficient related to it indicates how much being female affect the dependent variable outcome.
In your case it is stated that the dummy is not the main focus of the model, but just used to avoid omitted variable bias. 
Hope this helps
Paolo
Ps: btw 300 variables as predictors sound like an awful lot!